# Time-efficiently load data from pymongo to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, mongodb, pandas, filtering, pymongo

I am currently working with a MongoDB database into which I loaded ~30 Mio entries.

I need to retrieve the data from the database, filtered during the query, then transform it into a pandas DataFrame. The data is then used in a flask web application for plotting.

I tried several queries:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(list(db["demographics.sex"].find({"value": "male"})))
```

This returns 1.25 mio values and takes about 11 seconds.

I tried

```
data_list = list(db["demographics.sex"].find({"value": "male"}))
```

This takes about 8 seconds, so this step is already pretty time consuming.

Using only the query:

```
cursor = db["demographics.sex"].find({"value": "male"})
```

Takes 0-1 seconds.

So the most time consuming part seems is not the execution of the query and filter, but the transformation to a DataFrame.

Is there any method that does mongodb-->pandasdf more time-efficiently?

I would also be interested if the transformation to pandas is particularly inefficient? Is there a much better way to transport the data to a flask  powered web app?